# friendly-id - visit a resource with id but display slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Currently I need to use a resource :id to load a page, but thought it would be a nice touch to display the friendly id :slug by default. I am already using [norman/friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

If i visit

```
app.example.com/houses/1
```

I want the address bar to show me

```
app.example.com/houses/128-prinsep-st-singapore-1
```

Does friendly-id already support this? Or what would be a nice way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**FriendlyId provides a "slug candidates" functionality to let you specify alternate slugs to use in the event the one you want to use is already taken. For example:**

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :city],
      [:name, :street, :city],
      [:name, :street_number, :street, :city]
    ]
  end
end

e1 = Example.create! name: 'Plaza Diner', city: 'New Paltz'
e2 = Example.create! name: 'Plaza Diner', city: 'Kingston'

e1.friendly_id  #=> 'plaza-diner'
e2.friendly_id  #=> 'plaza-diner-kingston'
```

Hope this will work for you.